# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Usb networking stopped working - affected system is offline

Tags: networking, usb, ralink, offline

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 and everything was working great. I left my home for 7 days for a business trip and I came back to find that my usb networking has stopped working. Please consider me an user who has 10-12 days experience with Linux/Ubuntu. I made this post because I am completely offline on my desktop and most of the previous users who had issues related to the same device I am using were pretty old or they used online solution to fix something.

I can't connect to internet at all on my desktop. Fresh installation of Ubuntu had everything working from the start. Now I am unable to connect to the internet even via usb router. Sadly I do not have an ethernet based internet connection so I was unable to execute most of the common solutions available here on askubuntu.

my usb adapter is - Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601) - some searching on this device comes up with information that this adapter is now supported from 15.04 Ubuntu which was confirmed when I had it working from start on a fresh installation, so I did not follow those driver installation guide.

I also noticed while trying to collect information from my desktop that my usb pendrive was not being read, but lsusb was showing it as long as I had the usb wifi adapter plugged it. I removed the wifi adapter and rebooted and I could use the pendrive

I was unable to generate the required details from the post as my desktop is completely offline:
[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

but I was able to find some of the commands other users have used to provide information about their devices, I save them as .txt file from my desktop and transferred it to my laptop also running Ubuntu 18.04.1 to paste the output here.

One thing weird was dmesg returned some kind of error which I was unable to understand but it was a LOT of information. Another thing I noticed was my usb adapter is not letting me shutdown the system or I was not patient enough and just unplugged it. I see a text scrolling down with the usb adapter name mentioned after a few lines. And rfkill list all returns nothing..

Information related to the affected system : 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YFjgjRYg6q/

Comment: The dmesg output looks like defective or failed hardware to me. Buy a new network dongle.

Comment: But if that's the case then my router should connect via usb cable. Wired connection is also not working. Edit: Tested the usb adaptor on my uncle's windows system and it works

Comment: I will reinstall the os to see if that fixes the issue

Comment: Ok so the live usb drive also hanged when I inserted the usb network dongle, I have ordered a new network dongle, will let you guys know when it arrives.